# Install Numpy on Mac OS X Lion 10.7

Tags: xcode, macos, numpy, installation

I need to install Numpy on my Mac OS X Lion 10.7. I googled a little bit, it seems like there are a lot of stuff needs to be installed. And some says I need install Xcode before I install Numpy. But the official website of Numpy doesn't give much information about installing Numpy on Mac. I really don't want to install Xcode as it would cost a lot space.

So anyone knows how to install Numpy?  What's the prerequisites?

Thanks,

Comment: is the numpy that comes with osx not sufficient?

Comment: Sometimes it is not, for some software packages.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Generally, unless you have a good reason you might want to avoid trying to have to build numpy/scipy et al. yourself.

For Mac's there are two nice everything-included packages for numerical python. Enthough distribution (paid, http://www.enthought.com/) and Sagemath (free, http://www.sagemath.org/). I'm happily using Sagemath on 10.7 - it has numpy, scipy etc.

Answer (score 13):

Lion comes with numpy installed. It should already be there:

```
$ python -c 'import numpy, numpy.version; print numpy, numpy.version.version'
<module 'numpy' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/__init__.py'> 1.5.1
```

Answer (score 7):

For anyone that hits this from google, here is where I figured out how to build numpy on Mac OS.

http://www.scipy.org/Installing_SciPy/Mac_OS_X

On lion, it amounts to setting some environment variables (after Xcode is installed):

```
export CC=gcc-4.2
export CXX=g++-4.2
export FFLAGS=-ff2c
```

Then `pip install numpy` works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

I have used a few software packages that require a fresh install of NumPy, that won't work with the built in NumPy or even with the built-in Python. The easiest way to install NumPy on the mac is to download any of these packages. This will work for most OS versions.

- [Python 2.7](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.6.1/numpy-1.6.1-py2.7-python.org-macosx10.3.dmg/download)
- [Python 2.6](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.6.1/numpy-1.6.1-py2.6-python.org-macosx10.3.dmg/download)
- [Python 2.5](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.6.1/numpy-1.6.1-py2.5-python.org-macosx10.3.dmg/download)

Still the other answers are valid, though this is a more general answer.

This is the [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.6.1/) page of the project.

Answer (score 3):

If you do install Xcode you can get the latest and greatest open source libraries and packages.  Consider using the excellent Mac Ports (http://www.macports.org) project.  It is a package manager that will download source packages and their dependencies and build all the libraries and tools for you.

Installing Numpy becomes a one line command once Xcode and mac ports is installed:

`sudo port install py27-numpy`

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way that I found was to visit http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/, pick the folder of the latest version, and then download the .dmg file that matched my installed version of Python.

Comment: somehow this was the best option. Awesome!

Comment: this works, but notice you want a .dmg file like in El Developer's answer, but you want the OS 10.6 version not the OS 10.3 version that El Developer linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this post](http://nerdslearning.wordpress.com/2012/06/08/installing-scipy-on-mac-os-x-10-7-4-with-python-2-7-3/), I found that Chris Fonnesbeck keeps a highly functional installer script for OSX 10.7 at [the OSX SuperPack Github site](https://github.com/fonnesbeck/ScipySuperpack).

Because I hapened to have all the dependencies (such as gfortran) already, I did not use his full shell script.  Rather I just did

```
git clone --depth=1 git://github.com/fonnesbeck/ScipySuperpack.git  
python -m easy_install -N -Z ScipySuperpack/*.egg
```

And it worked beautifully.  In particular, it worked better than the `.dmg` files from the official numpy and scipy distributions, and better than `pip install`.

Answer (score 0):

You can install numpy/scipy using pip, If pip is not installed on your machine, you can install it with easy_install:

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

Then install numpy:

```
sudo pip install numpy
```

Answer (score 0):

A very easy route is to install [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads) from Continuum, or Enthought's [Canopy](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/). These are python distributions that include `numpy`, as well as other useful scientific computing libraries