# Numpy unit test failures in mountain lion

Tags: python, unit-testing, numpy, scipy, osx-mountain-lion

I am trying to install SciPy on my Mac OS 10.8.2 for Python 2.7.2. I have XCode 4.6 updated and with Command Line Tools installed. I installed numpy using pip as suggested in this thread [Numpy Installation on Mac 10.8.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106919/numpy-installation-on-mac-10-8-2) and am using the Fortran compilers from the High Performance Computing for Mac website (http://hpc.sourceforge.net/).

I am able to get numpy to install but when I try to run the built in SciPy unit test (as suggested in SciPy's installation documentation [here](http://www.scipy.org/Installing_SciPy/Mac_OS_X)) I continue to get FAIL for tests of basic arithmetic functions.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 20 2012, 16:23:33) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.test('full')
Running unit tests for numpy
NumPy version 1.6.1
NumPy is installed in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy
Python version 2.7.2 (default, Jun 20 2012, 16:23:33) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)]
nose version 1.2.1
..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................F............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................K.................................................................................................K......................K..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................F..............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................S.....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
======================================================================
FAIL: Test basic arithmetic function errors
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/testing/decorators.py", line 215, in knownfailer
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/tests/test_numeric.py", line 321, in test_floating_exceptions
    lambda a,b:a/b, ft_tiny, ft_max)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/tests/test_numeric.py", line 271, in assert_raises_fpe
    "Type %s did not raise fpe error '%s'." % (ftype, fpeerr))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/testing/utils.py", line 34, in assert_
    raise AssertionError(msg)
AssertionError: Type <type 'numpy.complex64'> did not raise fpe error ''.

======================================================================
FAIL: test_kind.TestKind.test_all
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/f2py/tests/test_kind.py", line 30, in test_all
    'selectedrealkind(%s): expected %r but got %r' %  (i, selected_real_kind(i), selectedrealkind(i)))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/testing/utils.py", line 34, in assert_
    raise AssertionError(msg)
AssertionError: selectedrealkind(19): expected -1 but got 16

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3552 tests in 35.919s

FAILED (KNOWNFAIL=3, SKIP=1, failures=2)
<nose.result.TextTestResult run=3552 errors=0 failures=2>
>>>
```

Related threads have suggested using the SciPy Superpack installer script by Chris Fonnesbeck, but this seems to be built for OS 10.7.

My gcc version is 4.2.1 and my gfortran version is 4.8.0

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Did you try to contact the numpy team about this?

Comment: I would contact Numpy, and also try the Python distribution for OsX from Enthought called EPD. It works for me, and was a simple install. http://epd-free.enthought.com/?Download=Download+EPD+Free+7.3-2

Comment: Did the EPD installation and now Numpy is working fine! Thanks so much for your help.