# Python import error invalid ELF header

Tags: python, numpy, biopython

When I try to use this command line to run this python code:

~/Tools/find_differential_primers/utils python stitch_six_frame_stops.py seq.fa

Error code will be displayed as followed. could you help me solve this problem.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stitch_six_frame_stops.py", line 55, in <module>
    import matplotlib
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib-1.3.x-py2.7-macosx-10.8 intel.egg/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 129, in <module>
    from matplotlib.cbook import is_string_like
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib-1.3.x-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/matplotlib/cbook.py", line 28, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy-1.8.0.dev_3084618_20130514-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/numpy/__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy-1.8.0.dev_3084618_20130514-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy-1.8.0.dev_3084618_20130514-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy-1.8.0.dev_3084618_20130514-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy-1.8.0.dev_3084618_20130514-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy-1.8.0.dev_3084618_20130514-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/numpy/core/multiarray.so: invalid ELF header
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use a .so file in Mac OSX! `.so` files work on Linux; Mac OSX works with `.dynld` files. You probably may want to verify your NumPy Installation.

Assuming you are using OSX Lion, please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338051/install-numpy-on-mac-os-x-lion-10-7) for how to install NumPy on the OSX.

Comment: actually I am using this code on a Ubuntu linux PC. I will try to re install my numpy first. Thx.