# Installing numpy on Mac to work on AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Is there a way to install `numpy` on a Mac so that it will work when uploaded to AWS Lambda? I have tried a variety of different ways, including using different `pip` versions, using `easy_install`, and following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338051/install-numpy-on-mac-os-x-lion-10-7), but none of them seem to work. I also tried cloning the git repo and building from there, but I also wasn't able to get that to work (though I'm not sure if I copied the right files up after doing that)

The error I'm getting is:

> Unable to import module 'lambda_function':  Importing the multiarray
>   numpy extension module failed.  Most likely you are trying to import a
>   failed build of numpy. If you're working with a numpy git repo, try
>   `git clean -xdf` (removes all files not under version control). 
>   Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34749806/using-moviepy-scipy-and-numpy-in-amazon-lambda), I was able to `pip install` `numpy` in a Linux environment and get it to work on Lambda.

So my question is: Is it possible to install `numpy` on a Mac so that it works on AWS Lambda?

Environment: MacBook Pro, MacOS 10.12.2, default python version 2.7.10

I've been testing it with a minor variation on the `hello-world-python` example on Lambda:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))
    print("value1 = " + event['key1'])
```

**(Update) Extending the question:** Why do some packages work and others don't?

Comment: You have to use a version built for Amazon Linux. You can't package Mac binaries in your Lambda deployment.

Comment: Thanks @MarkB. Do you know why that's the case for `numpy` and not for other packages? `numpy` is the only one where I've been running into this issue (so far). Asked another way - is there a way to know ahead of time which packages will require a Linux build?

Comment: You can unpackage the numpy whl file from the python project download files, there's a fuller answer here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43877692/pandas-in-aws-lambda-gives-numpy-error/52665589#52665589

Comment: @Tchotchke Probably because numpy is the only package you've used which has some parts written in C. The others are probably pure python, which is generally platform independent. Whereas C needs to be compiled into a binary which is specific to a platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on @MarkB's comment, it would not be possible to build `numpy` on a Mac to use on AWS Lambda. So why do some packages work and others don't?

Python extension modules, as explained on Mark Nunnikhoven's blog [here](https://markn.ca/2015/10/python-extension-modules-in-aws-lambda/), are

> written in C or C++ that can either extend python or call C or C++
>   libraries.

Since these modules are compiled specific to the system you're on, and AWS Lambda is a Linux environment, you'll need to install any extension modules on a Linux environment.

Answer (score 7):

Update: the preferred approach now is to just use the AWS-provided Lambda Layer for NumPy/SciPy, which is super easy to do.

In the console, select your function and then, under the "Design" section click on "Layers". Then click "Add a Layer", and select "AWSLambda-Python37-SciPy1x" under AWS Provided (or whatever the equivalent is for the version of Python you're using).

Then you can seamlessly import numpy, scipy, etc. into your code with no issues.

10/26/2020 - Added example screenshot:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Added screen shots to your answer, and also people can see this link: https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-amazon-lambda-layers-and-boto3-using-python3-39bd390add17

Answer (score 1):

Update: Please ignore the below and see my response above (here: [Installing numpy on Mac to work on AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42534850/installing-numpy-on-mac-to-work-on-aws-lambda/58136903#58136903)) about using Lambda Layers. That is a MUCH easier approach.

===========================================================================

I had this same exact issue and resolved it easily by following the advice here:

https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-python-packaging/

Note that I also had to add the lines:

```
package:
  exclude:
    - venv/**
```

... to the end of my serverless.yml to get my zip file under the size limit.

I will re-copy the instructions from the blog post below, just in case the link ever goes stale.

---

==============================================

## Create a Lambda Function that uses numpy

1. install node/npm
2. npm install -g serverless
3. configure aws for your computer (install the cli, run "aws configure" and add your credentials generated from IAM).
   3a. install Docker for Mac
  4.

## Run the following:

```
serverless create \
  --template aws-python3 \
  --name numpy-test \
  --path numpy-test

cd numpy-test
virtualenv venv --python=python3
source venv/bin/activate
```

5. edit handler.py and replace its contents with:

## handler.py

```
import numpy as np
def main(event, context):
    a = np.arange(15).reshape(3, 5)
    print("Your numpy array:")
    print(a)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main('', '')
```

6.

## Run the following:

```
pip3 install numpy
pip3 freeze > requirements.txt
cat requirements.txt
```

7. replace serverless.yml with:

## serverless.yml

```
service: numpy-test

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.6

functions:
  numpy:
    handler: handler.main
```

8. run the following

## run:

```
npm init
```

[accept defaults, then type "yes"]

```
npm install --save serverless-python-requirements
```

9. now replace serverless.yml with:

## serverless.yml

```
service: numpy-test

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.6

functions:
  numpy:
    handler: handler.main

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements

custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux

package:
  exclude:
    - venv/**
```

10. Run the following

## Run

```
serverless deploy --aws-profile [aws-account-you-want-to-upload-fxn-to]
serverless invoke -f numpy --log
```

11. If all goes well, you should see something like this:

## Expected output:

```
START RequestId: b32af7a8-52fb-4145-9e85-5985a0f64fe4 Version: $LATEST
Your numpy array:
[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14]]
END RequestId: b32af7a8-52fb-4145-9e85-5985a0f64fe4
REPORT RequestId: b32af7a8-52fb-4145-9e85-5985a0f64fe4  Duration: 0.52 ms    
Billed Duration: 100 ms     Memory Size: 1024 MB    Max Memory Used: 37 MB
```

Answer (score -1):

For using other packages which aren't available in AWS layers follow the following steps.

> 1. Go to your terminal
> 2. Make a directory named "python".
> 3. Go into the directory.
> 4. Enter "pip install " command.
> 5. Zip this file and add the zipped file to the AWS

Follow this link for more details : `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3BH79Uciw5w`