# Pandas in AWS lambda gives numpy error

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I've been trying to run my code in AWS Lambda which imports pandas. So here is what I've done.
I have a python file which contains a simple code as follows(This file has the lambda handler)

```
import json
print('Loading function')
import pandas as pd
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return "Welcome to Pandas usage in AWS Lambda"
```

1. I have zipped this python file along with numpy, pandas and pytz libraries as a deployment package (Did all these in Amazon EC2 linux machine)
2. Then uploaded the package into S3
3. Created a lambda function(runtime=python3.6) and uploaded the deployment package from S3

But when I test the lambda function in AWS Lambda, I get the below error:

```
Unable to import module 'lambda_function': Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

I already have numpy in the zipped package but still I get this error. I tried to follow the hints given at [Pandas & AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36054976/pandas-aws-lambda) but no luck.

Did anyone ran into the same issue. Would appreciate any hint or suggestions to solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Wow, I didn't know this was so easy (I have been writing my own pandas-like helpers in vanilla python for aws lambda).

Comment: Did you compile pandas, numpy etc on that amazon linux machine? Because you need to compile them there, not just zip.

Comment: @AdamOwczarczyk thanks for your reply. I spent so much time to figure out how to compile/build the packages. In this attempt, I followed this blog post (https://blog.datapolitan.com/2015/08/25/installing-matplotlib-and-pandas-on-amazon-ec2/). But still not luck :(

Comment: I have wrote a blog post about this, and I tested with Numpy pre-compiled library. https://medium.com/the-python-backend/hassle-free-python-lambda-deployment-tutorial-script-9c65bcf47e26

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas & AWS Lambda](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36054976/pandas-aws-lambda)

Comment: It is not a duplicate. The link to which you are referring is where the runtime is python2.7. But in my case the runtime is python3.6. If I had to use python2.7, then it is working for me too and I don't have to ask a question here in that case. But runtime is different here pals!

Comment: For future readers: a lot of people seem to import pandas or numpy to perform trivial list transformations without realizing how big and overkill these libraries are. Often you can avoid them completely with stock Python list features. That's a much better option with AWS Lambda.

Answer (score 15):

To include numpy in your lambda zip follow the instructions on this page in the AWS docs...

[How do I add Python packages with compiled binaries to my deployment package and make the package compatible with AWS Lambda?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-python-package-compatible/)

To paraphrase the instructions using numpy as an example:

1. Open the module pages at pypi.org. 
   https://pypi.org/project/numpy/
2. Choose Download files.
3. Download:

For Python 2.7, module-name-version-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl

e.g. numpy-1.15.2-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl

For Python 3.6, module-name-version-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl

e.g. numpy-1.15.2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl

4. Uncompress the wheel file on the /path/to/project-dir folder.
   You can use the unzip command on the command line to do this. There are other ways obviously.

`unzip numpy-1.15.2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl`

When the wheel file is uncompressed, your deployment package will be compatible with Lambda.

Hope that all makes sense ;)

The end result might look something like this.
Note: you should not include the whl file in the deployment package.

[image: What it might look like]

Comment: I am facing same issue, when i copy numpy like this pandas gave this error-  C extension: No module named 'pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion' not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force' to build the C extensions first. --  any idea about this

Comment: I did the same as this tutorial, step by step and I it was not successfull  https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-python-package-compatible/.

So I also follow this AWS oficial tutorial and so I have the same issue again: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-python-package-compatible/.

I don't know what to do anymore. Some idea? I'am using Mac OS.

Comment: This worked for me! I had been using Python3.7 runtime environment in AWS Lambda, instead of Python3.6 which everybody else seems to be using. Anyway, I just downloaded the numpy cp37-cp37m-manylinux_x86_64.whl, then I unzipped it, then I have a zip with my `lambda_function.py`, `numpy` directory, and `numpy.dist-info` directory! Upload, and bam! It's all good. No installation through EC2 needed, no docker. Plain and simple, how I like it!

Comment: @Dimuthu any solution? I am facing the same problem

Answer (score 12):

EDIT: I figured out finally how to run pandas & numpy in a AWS Lambda python 3.6 runtime environment.

I have uploaded my deployment package to the following repo:

`git clone https://github.com/pbegle/aws-lambda-py3.6-pandas-numpy.git`

Simply add your `lambda_function.py` to the zip file by running:

`zip -ur lambda.zip lambda_function.py`

Upload to S3 and source to lambda.

ORIGINAL:

The only way I have gotten Pandas to work in a lambda function is by compiling the pandas (and numpy) libraries in an AWS Linux EC2 instance following the steps from [this blog post](https://streetdatascience.com/2016/11/24/using-numpy-and-pandas-on-aws-lambda/) and then using the python 2.7 runtime for my lambda function.

Comment: Would love to know how it can be done in a python 3.6 runtime environment though if anyone figures it out!

Comment: would you be able to explain how you did this? I would like to be able to extend this to other packages. Thanks!

Comment: I wrote a blog post on exactly how to do it. Check it out:
https://medium.com/i-like-big-data-and-i-cannot-lie/how-to-create-an-aws-lambda-python-3-6-deployment-package-using-docker-d0e847207dd6

Comment: I ran into a similar issue now. Simply took all the subfolder from this repo and used with the lambda I'm trying to upload. This does the work too

Answer (score 12):

After doing a lot of research I was able to make it work with Lambda layers.

Create or open a clean directory and follow the steps below:

**Prerequisites**: Make sure you have Docker up and running

1. Create a **requirements.txt** file with the following:

> ```
> pandas==0.23.4
> pytz==2018.7
> ```

2. Create a **get_layer_packages.sh** file with the following:

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
>
> export PKG_DIR="python"
>
> rm -rf ${PKG_DIR} && mkdir -p ${PKG_DIR}
>
> docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/foo -w /foo lambci/lambda:build-python3.6 \
>     pip install -r requirements.txt --no-deps -t ${PKG_DIR}
> ```

3. Run the following commands in the same directory:

> ```
> chmod +x get_layer_packages.sh
>
> ./get_layer_packages.sh
>
> zip -r pandas.zip .
> ```

4. Upload the layer to a S3 bucket.
5. Upload the layer to AWS by running the command below:

> ```
> aws lambda publish-layer-version --layer-name pandas-layer --description "Description of your layer"
> --content S3Bucket=<bucket name>,S3Key=<layer-name>.zip
> --compatible-runtimes python3.6 python3.7
> ```

6. Go to Lambda console and upload your code as a zip file or use the inline editor.
7. Click on Layers > Add a layer> Search for the layer (pandas-layer) from the Compatible layers and select the version.
8. Also add the AWSLambda-Python36-SciPy1x layer which is available by default for importing numpy.

[Selecting the layer from the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wcv3.png)

9. Test the code. It should work now!!!!

*Thanks to this medium article https://medium.com/@qtangs/creating-new-aws-lambda-layer-for-python-pandas-library-348b126e9f3e*

Comment: Do you have to specify the version in the requirements.txt file?

Answer (score 8):

[AWS Lambda use Amazon Linux](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html) operating system. Idea is download [Pandas](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/) and [NumPy](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/) compatible with [Amazon Linux](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/). What you download using `pip` is specific to Windows or Mac. You need to download the compatible version for Linux, so that your Lambda function can understand it. These files are called `wheel` files.

Create new local directory with `lambda_function.py` file. Install Pandas to local directory with pip:

```
$ pip install -t . pandas
```

Navigate to https://pypi.org/project/pandas/#files. Search for and download newest `*manylinux1_x86_64.whl` package. In my case, I'm using Python 3.6 on my Lambda function, so I downloaded the following:

- Pandas - [pandas-0.24.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e6/de/a0d3defd8f338eaf53ef716e40ef6d6c277c35d50e09b586e170169cdf0d/pandas-0.24.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl)
- NumPy - [numpy-1.16.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f5/bf/4981bcbee43934f0adb8f764a1e70ab0ee5a448f6505bd04a87a2fda2a8b/numpy-1.16.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl)

Download whl files to directory with `lambda_function.py`. Remove `pandas`, `numpy`, and `*.dist-info` directories. Unzip whl files.

```
$ rm -r pandas numpy *.dist-info
$ unzip numpy-1.16.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
$ unzip pandas-0.24.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
```

Remove whl files, `*.dist-info`, and `__pycache__`. Prepare `zip.zip` archive:

```
$ rm -r *.whl *.dist-info __pycache__
$ zip -r zip.zip .
```

Upload the `zip.zip` file in your Lambda function.

[image]

Source: https://medium.com/@korniichuk/lambda-with-pandas-fd81aa2ff25e

Answer (score 3):

The main problem is that libraries compiled within a specific OS will only work for that OS. So, if a library is compiled within macOS then it will not run in Linux environment. Why is this a problem?

One of the dependencies of Pandas is Numpy (which is compiled due to speed, [see this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385602/why-are-numpy-arrays-so-fast/55946435#55946435)). AWS Lambda uses Linux hence if the Numpy compilation is done within macOS or windows, then the compilation will only be good for those specific architectures and will not work within AWS. I think those using Linux will not experience this problem.

To solve this problem and create a working AWS Lambda layer for Pandas, follow these simple steps ([see the general steps on amazon forum](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-python-package-compatible/)):

```
mkdir awsPandasLayer #create a directory
cd awsPandasLayer #cd into the directory
pip3 install -t . Pandas #install pandas and all its dependencies 
rm -r pandas numpy *.dist-info __pycache__ #clean up the environment to remove the incompatible numpy and pandas
```

Then download the latest precompiled packages for [Pandas](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/#files) and [Numpy](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/#files) into the awsPandasLayer directory earlier created. For my case, since I am using Python 3.7, I downloaded these versions of [Pandas](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/af/f3/683bf2547a3eaeec15b39cef86f61e921b3b187f250fcd2b5c5fb4386369/pandas-1.0.5-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl) and [Numpy](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d6/c6/58e517e8b1fb192725cfa23c01c2e60e4e6699314ee9684a1c5f5c9b27e1/numpy-1.18.5-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl). Notice cp37 denotes the python version as clearly stated on the site. Then complete the installation as follows:

```
unzip pandas-1.0.5-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl #unzip the pandas precompiled package
unzip numpy-1.18.5-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl #unzip the numpy precompiled package
pip3 install -t . openpyxl #I found this is required within AWS Lambda for excel files
rm -r *.whl *.dist-info __pycache__ #clean up unneeded files
zip -r awsPandasLayer.zip . # zip all the files
```

The zip file can then be uploaded as an AWS Lambda layer and it should work. Note that I am using macOS.

Answer (score 2):

To get additional libraries in Lambda we need to compile them on Amazon Linux (this is important if the underlying library is based on C or C++ like for Numpy) and package them in a ZIP file together with the python script you want to run in Lambda.

To get the Amazon Linux compiled version of the libraries. You can either find a version that someone already compiled, like the one by @pbegle, or compile it yourself. To compile it ourself there are two options:
 - compile the libraries on an EC2 instance https://streetdatascience.com/2016/11/24/using-numpy-and-pandas-on-aws-lambda/
 - compile the libraries on a docker version of Lambda environment
https://serverlesscode.com/post/scikitlearn-with-amazon-linux-container/

Following the last option with Docker, it is possible to make it work using the instructions in the blog post above and by adding:

```
pip install --use-wheel pandas
```

in the script to compile the libraries:

https://github.com/ryansb/sklearn-build-lambda/blob/master/build.sh#L21

Comment: i've tryed that, but the resulting zip file is about 55MB. 
any update on that?

Answer (score 2):

Consider using AWS Layer. Worked for me on 11Dec2022 with runtime=Python3.9 and architecture=x86_64

- Under 'Function overview', select 'Layers' (alternatively just scroll to the bottom of the function's page)
  [Function overview > Layers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54hvk.png)
- Select 'Add a layer', and add AWS layer 'AWSSDKPandas-Python39' as shown:
  [Add a layer > AWSSDKPandas-Python39](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBZJf.png)

Hope this saves you the hours I spent :)

Answer (score 1):

Slightly duplicate of [Cannot find MySQL in NodeJS using AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45204038/cannot-find-mysql-in-nodejs-using-aws-lambda/45204186#45204186)

You need to package your libraries with Lambda. As lambda runs on a public cloud, you cannot configure it.

Now in your case, as you are using pandas, you need to package Pandas with your zip. Get a path to pandas(for example: /Users/dummyUser/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages) and copy the library to the place where you have your lambda function code. Inside your code, refer to pandas from your local copy. While uploading, zip the whole set(code + libraries), and upload as you will. It should work.

Comment: This is what I did but its still missing

Answer (score 1):

I tried some of the solution here but most of them didn't work. I liked the idea @Ranadeep Guha suggested of creating a container and downloading the repos over there so that's what I did.

I worked in the dir my lambda function was located on and created the following files :

Dockerfile :

```
FROM python:3.8-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt -t /app
```

requirements.txt : (those were mine)

```
pandas
numpy
xmltodict
```

Now in my gitbash I run the following command that will generate a docker image for me with all the dependencies installed :

```
docker build -t image_name .

Sending build context to Docker daemon  5.632kB
Step 1/4 : FROM python:3.8-slim
 ---> 56930ef6f6a2
Step 2/4 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ea0bf539bcad
Step 3/4 : COPY requirements.txt ./
 ---> cb4c005f53cc
Step 4/4 : RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt -t /app
 ---> Running in a0d179a372b4
Collecting pandas
  Downloading pandas-1.0.3-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (10.0 MB)
Collecting numpy
  Downloading numpy-1.18.3-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (20.6 MB)
Collecting xmltodict
  Downloading xmltodict-0.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.2 kB)
Collecting pytz>=2017.2
  Downloading pytz-2020.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510 kB)
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.6.1
  Downloading python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (227 kB)
Collecting six>=1.5
  Downloading six-1.14.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Installing collected packages: numpy, pytz, six, python-dateutil, pandas, xmltodict
Successfully installed numpy-1.18.3 pandas-1.0.3 python-dateutil-2.8.1 pytz-2020.1 six-1.14.0 xmltodict-0.12.0
```

Now just create a Docker container of that image and confirm that everything installed :

```
winpty docker run --name container_name -it --entrypoint bash image_name
```

type ls and you will see all the installs.

Now let's copy all the installs to your local pc. You can replace the dot with any location on your pc:

```
 docker cp container_id:/app/* .
```

Answer (score 1):

Using ideas from these answers and SO 55695187, I've built a layer for AWS Lambda containing pandas and made it available at github. It has pandas v 1.3.1 for Python 3.8. See https://github.com/eoneil1942/pandas. Here is what I did:

```
Created an ec2 instance for AWS Linux
Installed python3.8, pip3, used pip3 to install pandas
Made an empty directory python/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Copied pandas and pytz from installed site-packages to this one
zip -r pandas.zip python
```

Clearly this generalizes to any Python package.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

1. In lambda code only import libraries (Not push the libraries in .zip):

   `from scipy.stats import norm`

   `import pandas as pd`

   `...`
2. Then in lambda console, add layers with ARN option:

   Scipy-numpy:
   `arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:668099181075:layer:AWSLambda-Python38-SciPy1x:29`

   Pandas:
   `arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:770693421928:layer:Klayers-python38-pandas:42`
3. Test your lambda.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with a similar error while trying to use the python3.6 engine. When I switched to 2.7 it worked fine for me. I used Amazon AMI to create my zip file, but it has only python3.5, not 3.6. I guess the version mismatch was the reason. But it's just a guess, I haven't tried the process on a python3.6 installation yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to Randeep's answer but you don't need to use Lambda Layers if you don't want to do that.

As others have stated, this is not working because pandas/numpy require binaries to be built and the operating system of your build machine (Linux, Mac, Windows) does not match the operating system of Lambda (Amazon Linux).

To solve this, you can use docker to download/build your dependencies and package them up on Amazon Linux.  Amazon provides a Docker image for this purpose.  See below for how I built my python package for Python 3.6 runtime (they have other dockers for all other runtimes):

Put all of your dependencies into a `requirements.txt` file, for example:

```
openpyxl
boto3
pandas
```

Create a script (i.e. named `build.sh`) that will build your package, here is what mine looked like:

```
#!/bin/bash

# remove old build artifacts
rm -rf build
rm lambda_package.zip

# make build dir and copy my lambda handler file into it
mkdir build
cp lambda_daily_util_gen.py  build/

# Use requirements file to download/build dependencies into the build folder
cd build
pip install -r ../requirements.txt --target .

# Create an lambda package with my files and all dependencies
zip -r9 ../lambda_package.zip .
```

Ensure you have the Amazon Linux lambda build image pulled:

```
$ docker pull lambci/lambda
```

Run your build script inside of the docker container:

Windows:

```
$ docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/var/task lambci/lambda:build-python3.6 /var/task/build.sh
```

Mac/Linux:

```
docker run --rm -v ${PWD}:/var/task lambci/lambda:build-python3.6 chmod +x build.sh;./build.sh
```

You should now see a file named `lambda_package.zip` that was built on Amazon Linux you can upload to AWS.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

with the [serverless framework](https://serverless.com/), you can easily package and deploy your dependencies correctly.

you only need to;

1. install serverless

   ```
   npm install -g serverless
   ```
2. create a serverless.yml in the root of your project with the following:

   ```
   service: numpy-test

   # define the environment of your lambda
   provider:
     name: aws
     runtime: python3.6

   # specify the function you want to deploy
   functions:
     numpy:
       # path to your lambda_handler function
       handler: path/to/function.lambda_handler

   # add a plugin that allows serverless to package python libraries
   # specified in the requirements.txt or Pipfile
   plugins:
     - serverless-python-requirements

   # this section makes sure your libraries get build correctly 
   # for an aws lambda environment
   custom:
     pythonRequirements:
       dockerizePip: non-linux
   ```

   > adjust the path/to/function.lambda_handler
3. make sure docker is running and execute

   `serverless deploy`

once the deployment is finished, go to the AWS console look for the function *numpy-test-dev-numpy* and test your function.

**[this article](https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-python-packaging/) explains the necessary steps in detail.**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe module you're using is for python 2.7.

Try install pandas module for python 3.x

i.e.

> pip3 install pandas -t .

It worked for me.

Or for instant result, Change your runtime to python 2.7 **(not recommended)**

Answer (score 0):

To make a deployment package that's compatible with Lambda, download a precompiled package called a wheel (.whl). Uncompress the wheel file on /path/to/project-dir **instead of using pip install.**

Resolution

1. Open your module-name pypi.org page. For example:
   https://pypi.org/project/numpy/
2. Choose Download files.
3. Download:

For Python 2.7, module-name-version-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
For Python 3.6, module-name-version-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
4.    Uncompress the wheel file on the /path/to/project-dir folder.

When the wheel file is uncompressed, your deployment package will be compatible with Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only thing that worked for me: [Python packages in AWS Lambda made easy](https://towardsdatascience.com/python-packages-in-aws-lambda-made-easy-8fbc78520e30)

Paraphrasing what they did, this is a small summary of the steps you need to follow:

**1 - Install packages in Linux instance**

Like other users mentioned, you need to install libraries in a linux instance to make sure it works with your Lambda Function. You can use AWS [Cloud9](https://aws.amazon.com/cloud9/) service to do this.

- Go to Cloud9 in AWS and click *Create Environment*
- Name the environment, select a t2.micro and leave the rest with default settings: [image]
- Click next step to review the settings and finally click on *Create environment*

**2 - Create Panda Layer**

On the new environment, use the next code to install panda library (which includes numpy):

(*Note: You can install more than one module*)

```
mkdir folder
cd folder
virtualenv v-env
source ./v-env/bin/activate
pip install pandas
deactivate
```

Type the next code to zip de necessary files and publish the layer version into your aws account:

```
mkdir python
cd python
cp -r ../v-env/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/* .
cd ..
zip -r panda_layer.zip python
aws lambda publish-layer-version --layer-name pandas --zip-file fileb://panda_layer.zip --compatible-runtimes python3.7
```

**3 - Add the layer to your lambda**

Once you've completed step 2, you will have a layer called *pandas* in Lambda section in aws (you can see it on the left menu). Make sure that you've selected Runtime 3.7 for your lambda:

[image]

Click on *Add Layer* on the bottom of the page in your Lambda configuration and select the new Layer you've just created.

You can test the Lambda just by importing numpy and pandas. You'll see that you can execute it just fine.

**Finally:**

**Remember to delete your Cloud9 environment!** You can go to AWS Cloud9 section and remove the environment previously created by selecting it and clicking delete. It should terminate the EC2 instance associated with it, but to make sure, go to EC2 section in AWS and check that the instance state is *Terminated*. If not, click on it and on *Instance state* select *Terminate instance*.

Make sure to check the Guide mentioned above to support their work.

Answer (score 0):

For those still hitting this in 2022 (March 29th to be specific), I encountered this whilst using AWS SAM to build Lambdas. I had the same `import pandas as pd` line as OP, but my `template.yaml` was specifying to build on ARM (because it was originally written on a Mac). However, I was packaging and deploying from a windows machine.

So, **changing the template from ARM to x86_64** solved the problem for me. I did also bundle in `pytz` and `numpy` to my dependencies, but that didn't initially solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Now I wanted to run pandas, numpy and chart_studio (or plotly) plotly worked using the mac zipped file using pip3 install chart_studio -t . in the directory, but pandas and numpy would not work at all using this method. But python worked by putting the layers of the wheel files of pandas and numpy and adding layers in lambda, but now plotly would not work because with plotly it says its too large to load the layers.
What I did to finally get it to work is use the wheel files and add layers for pandas and numpy and also did the pip3 install chart_studio -t . and zipped it with the python file to execute and it finally worked when I combined the two methods. Hope you guys are successful with this tip.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a layer of pandas, numpy and pytz libraries. then attach it to lamdba function.
to make library for python 3.7 (replace python3.7 with python3.6 for python 3.6):

```
docker run -v "PWD":/var/task "lambci/lambda:build-python3.7" /bin/sh -c "pip install pandas numpy pytz -t python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/; exit"
```

it will create a folder **python**. Now zip this folder and upload to lambda layer, attach it with your function

Answer (score 0):

Got this issue running python3.9 on arm64. Built on MacOS 13.2.1 on M1Max using:

```
sam build --parallel && sam deploy
```

Was solved by building in a container using `--use-container`.

The comments [here](https://repost.aws/questions/QUGPaWtQOuRBCLP8z_erolrQ/aws-lambda-layers-with-python-package) suggested this was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Lambda console, click on the 'Add Layers' at the bottom of your lambda, select AWS Layers, and click on AWSSDKPandas-Python311 (or the layer associated with your python version since I was using Python3.11)

You will be able to run numpy, as well as any package it also loads such as pandas.
[image: AWS Managed Lambda Layer that has numpy]

Answer (score -2):

Your code always give this error
because lambda does not contain any external library it having a library which by default come with Python.

**if you are using any external library like pandas, numpy or any other. you need to install that library on Aws Lambda** 

 before using it

see you code

```
import json
print('Loading function')
import pandas as pd
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return "Welcome to Pandas usage in AWS Lambda"
```

here no installation of pandas library so your code is not working. 

my suggestion is use your code as follows. write all you code inside the lambda function

```
import json
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #install python libray here 
    print('Loading function')
    import pandas as pd
    return "Welcome to Pandas usage in AWS Lambda"
```

**So final code look as follows**

```
 def lambda_handler(event, context):
     import pip

    def install(package):
        if hasattr(pip, 'main'):
            pip.main(['install', package])
        else:
            pip._internal.main(['install', package])

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        install('pandas')

    #install python libray here 
    print('Loading function')
    import pandas as pd
    return "Welcome to Pandas usage in AWS Lambda"
```

Comment: That's not recommended as an approach, you should bundle the libraries into the deployment package.