# Lambda function giving mysql error Cannot find module 'mysql' is not a function, even after including it in zip

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, aws-lambda

I created a lambda function using the following method.

1. Inside a new folder I ran

   npm init

   to initialize a new project
2. Then I added my code to index.js and ran

   npm install mysql --save

   to save mysql package locally.
3. After this I zipped the content of this new folder and uploaded the zip to lambda functions.
4. I ran the test using test in the console and got this error.

   {
   "errorType": "Error",
   "errorMessage": "Cannot find module 'mysql'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/index.js\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js",
   "trace": [
   "Error: Cannot find module 'mysql'",
   "Require stack:",
   "- /var/task/index.js",
   "- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js",
   "- /var/runtime/index.js",
   "    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)",
   "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)",
   "    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)",
   "    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)",
   "    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:4:17)",
   "    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"
   ]
   }

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the trouble is the uploaded zip file doesnt contains the `mysql` package you installed or the path your code is looking for the dependencies is not correct.

You can verify that by downloading the zip file.

As you did not mention how you are deploying all these resources.

I would suggest use any framework,

1. [Serverless Framework](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/intro/)
2. [AWS SAM](https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/sam/)

which takes care of your packaging your dependencies and you can deploy them with confidence.

[Cannot find MySQL in NodeJS using AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45204186/2246345)