# AWS Lambda Python 3.7 :Unable to import module 'lambda_function': Missing required dependencies ['numpy']

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-3.7

Same code is working in my local machine, however getting the below error when I tried to test in the AWS Lambda:

> Unable to import module 'lambda_function': Missing required dependencies ['numpy']

Comment: there is a fix for 3.6 here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43877692/pandas-in-aws-lambda-gives-numpy-error

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the packages from pypi.org and include them on the zip file that contains both, the code in a py file and the packages. Find a more detailed description here https://www.protos-technologie.de/en/2020/07/02/dependency-management-for-aws-lambda/.