# do numpy 1.19 work with python 3.6 and pandas 1.15 ? If not what version do I have to use?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, aws-lambda, python-3.6

The error I am facing is:

> Unable to import module 'lambda_function': Unable to import required dependencies:
> numpy:
>
> IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!
>
> Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
> many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
> installed.
>
> Please note and check the following:
>
> ```
>  * The Python version is: Python3.6 from "/var/lang/bin/python3.6"
>  * The NumPy version is: "1.19.0"
> ```
>
> Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

Please help me know what I need to do to fix this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas in AWS lambda gives numpy error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43877692/pandas-in-aws-lambda-gives-numpy-error)

Answer (score -1):

Just run command :
Import numpy
numpy --upgrage

And you can chek version by :
Print (numpy.**version**)